# How to Use control Commands in Kusto Function

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am ingesting json data from EventHub to my ADX-Kusto database table. Till here it is fine. Suppose If Ingestion fails due to some corrupt data, I could use the command `.show ingestion failures | project <specific columns>` to display the failure ingestion results. But When I try to wrap the command in-side a function, It throws Error. I get to know that we can't wrap control commands inside a function.
Now,

1. I want to trigger a function whenever ingestion failure happens.
2. Alert email notification if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can offer you is to use Microsoft Flow or Azure Function to perform this task - periodically look for failures and issue mails.

There is no support for triggering anything by an ingestion failure - at high rates this simply is unfeasible.

Going forward we are planning to offer additional options for monitoring the ingest operations. Stay tuned.

UPDATE: it is now possible to monitor all ingestion operations using Diagnostic logs. [Azure Data Explorer ingestion operations monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs) is now available in preview.

Comment: accepting answer. Please update here for ingestion monitoring.